# The 2nd total derivative (Hessian) of a composite function -Version 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

> Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ and
>
> $Df:A\subset\mathbb R^n\to L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ so that  $Df_x:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is $f$'s total derivative at  $x\in\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Let $f$'s Hessian at the point $x$ be $Hf_x: \mathbb R^n \times  \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, defined (as a bilinear form) by
> $$Hf_x(x_1,x_2)=[[D(Df)_x] (x_2)](x_1).$$    Further, let $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and define $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by  $$g(t)=f(a+xt).$$

In a proof that $f(a)$ is a local max implies that $Hf_a$ is negative
semidefinite, I encountered the following assertion, but I aren't able
to see why: $$Hg_0(1,1)=Hf_a(x,x).$$

Comment: Great question! Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule,

$$Dg_s(t_1) = Df_{(a+tx)(s)}\left[D(a+tx)_s(t_1)\right] = Df_{a+sx}\left[x(s) (t_1)\right]=Df_{a+sx}(xt_1)$$
and
$$Hg_s(t_1,t_2) = D(Dg_t(t_1))_s(t_2) = D(Df_{a+tx}(xt_1))_s(t_2) = D\left[\left(Df_t \circ (a+tx)\right)(xt_1)\right]_{s}(t_2).$$
Applying the chain rule again to this last expression gives
$$D[Df_t(xt_1)]_{a+xs}(D_s(a+xt)(t_2)) = Hf_{a+sx}(xt_1,x(s)(t_2))= Hf_{a+sx}(xt_1,xt_2).$$

Plugging in $s=0$ and $t_1=t_2=1$ gives you the desired identity.

Comment: The chain rule says $D_pf(g)(v) = Df_{g(p)}(D_pg(v)).$

Comment: Intuitively, you first map a tangent vector at $p$ to a tangent vector at $g(p)$. Then, you map that tangent vector from $g(p)$ to $f(g(p))$.

Comment: I've added more detail above. Maybe there was confusion about $t$ as the function parameter vs. $t$ as the point of evaluation?

Comment: If you are still stuck I think it would be easier for you to edit your post with your full calculation, and I can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I've added more details about the second derivative.